# Every function $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ admits a weak derivative.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, riesz-representation-theorem

I have write a little argument that seems to show that every function $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ admits a weak derivative:

Let $f \in L^2(\Omega)$. We define the functional on $H^1(\Omega) = W^{1, 2}(\Omega)$
$$\mathcal F: H^1(\Omega) \to \mathbb R: u \mapsto -\int_\Omega f\partial_iu$$
which is continuous because
$$|\mathcal F(u)| \le \|f\|_2 \|u\|_{1, 2}.$$
By Riesz representation theorem, there is $\tilde{f}\in H^1(\Omega)$ such that
$$\int_\Omega \tilde{f}u = -\int_\Omega f\partial_iu, \quad \forall u \in H^1(\Omega).$$
As $C^\infty_0(\Omega) \subset H^1(\Omega)$, this equality is true for all $u \in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$. Moreover, as $\tilde{f} \in H^1(\Omega)$, in particular $\tilde{f} \in L^2(\Omega)$ so that $f$ admits a weak derivative given by $\tilde{f}$.

This argument has to be wrong because not all functions $L^2(\Omega)$ have a weak derivative but I really don't see where is my error. Could one have you help me with this ?

Comment: when using Riesz representation theorem. You use it on the Hilbert space $H = H^1(\Omega)$, so you would have 

$$ \tag{1}\int_\Omega \tilde fu + \int_\Omega D \tilde f \cdot Du = \langle \tilde f, u\rangle _H= -\int_\Omega f \partial_i u$$

instead of 
$$ \int_\Omega \tilde f u =\langle \tilde f, u\rangle_{L^2}= -\int_\Omega f \partial_i u.$$

Comment: @ArcticChar This is a full answer, really nothing more to say about it. Maybe post it as an answer so that this question doesn't keep dangling?

Comment: I thought about that (indeed I almost posted it), but I am not 100% sure that (1) cannot imply that $f$ is weakly differentiable (of course it shouldn't  be....) . @MaoWao

Comment: @ArcticChar this is showing the flaw in the argument. Of course this is not a proof that every $L^2$ function does not have weak derivative, which is false ofc.